# Scope weirdness when recursing

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am just playing aimlessly, and I stumbled across something I don't get.

```
var result;
// [.............. more stuff ..............]
function iterate(n) {
 if (isDivisor(n)) {
   if (checkIfPrime(n)) {
        result = n;
        return result;
   }
   iterate(n-2);
 }
 iterate(n-2);
}

result = iterate(startN)
console.warn("result is ", result)

//(isDivisor() and checkIfPrime() omitted because irrelevant to the problem
```

So, the code works fine, in the restrict sense that the recursion stops once the expected value is reached. But! in the console I get `undefined`.
`result` is a global and is not redeclared inside any function, specifically not inside `iterate()`. `n` has the correct value when `iterate()` returns. `iterate()` has access to the global scope (and lives into it) So, how could it possibly result be `undefined`... ?

I am probably only having a selective blindness attack but I really don't see where the scope goes astray.

Comment: You're setting "result" to be the value returned from a call to "iterate()".  However, you don't ever actually return anything from that function.

Comment: You might have a point. Gonna try another pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Your function returns undefined, and you are assigning its result to the result variable.

You should return the result from the function:

```
function iterate(n) {
 if (isDivisor(n)) {
   if (checkIfPrime(n)) {
        return n;
   }
   return iterate(n-2);
 }
 return iterate(n-2);
}

var result = iterate(startN);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Alas, no, Arnaud. That was my first port of call but returns undefined. If I log the value of `n` just before the return, `n` has the expected value. What happens is only that `n` fails to be assigned to `result`, and I don't get why.

Comment: Scratch that. You're right. I had omitted to return the value from the "failed" iterations.

Answer (score 3):

If a Javascript fiunction exits without getting to a return statement, its return value will be `undefined`. This will happen to your function unless you have `isDivisor(n)` and `checkIfPrime(n)` both being true.

Perhaps you were intending to do

```
function iterate(n) {
 if (isDivisor(n)) {
   if (checkIfPrime(n)) {
        result = n;
        return result;
   }
   return iterate(n-2); // <----
 }
 return iterate(n-2); // <----
}
```

instead?

Comment: Yeah, it's intended behaviour, and indeed the function exits correctly, it just fails to assign the returned value to `result`. That's what amazes me :)

Comment: Yup, both valid answers and indeed I was being blind. Thanks a lot! :D